# Get common desktop path in .NET

Tags: .net, windows, windows-shell

I need to store files into the common desktop on Windows. The application is a very special application for exactly one special PC (device preparation), so it had to be easy for non-techie users to find and modify the configuration file. Now we switched to a domain, and because different people (with different accounts) should use the software, it has to be in a common place, seen by every user. So please don't ask why it's on the desktop ;)

Previously, I just used `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)`. There are several of the common folders in the `SpecialFolder` enumeration, but the common desktop seems not to be there. Am I missing something, or do I have to p/invoke `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` with `CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY`?

Comment: Now it gets dirty. Unfortunately, it seems I have by default no rights to write to the common desktop, which makes this complicated. Any suggestions for a better location? Remember that the user should be able to find the file, and all users need read/write access. The application should by XCOPY-deployed.

Comment: While the original question stays valid (especially since it seems not be anywhere on SO), I think I'll have to go with common documents (or whatever the name on English systems is). That's still kind of findable by the user. Now let's just hope I have write access. Feel free to comment if you think that this is a good/bad idea.

Comment: Why don't you store them in a machine scope isolated storage?

Comment: @David Brunelle: I'll have a look, thanks.

Comment: Damn. I knew I should put that in an answer instead. Could've get some vote... :o

Comment: @David Brunelle: Though that might solve my underlying problem, it wouldn't be a correct answer to this question :)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe there  is not a better answer for this!

Comment: Note that in .NET 4.0, the `SpecialFolder` enumeration contains `CommonDesktopDirectory`, which is likely what I was asking for. Just too late ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use the `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` API, since there is no enum value for "CommonDesktopDirectory". You can't explicitly use the value of `CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY` and cast it to `Environment.SpecialFolder`, because the `GetFolderPath` method checks that the value is defined in the enum. Here's the code of the `GetFolderPath` method (from Reflector) :

```
public static string GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder folder)
{
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(SpecialFolder), folder))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, GetResourceString("Arg_EnumIllegalVal"), new object[] { (int) folder }));
    }
    StringBuilder lpszPath = new StringBuilder(260);
    Win32Native.SHGetFolderPath(IntPtr.Zero, (int) folder, IntPtr.Zero, 0, lpszPath);
    string path = lpszPath.ToString();
    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery, path).Demand();
    return path;
}
```

So you can easily copy and adapt the part that you need...

Comment: OK, I just wanted to be sure. Now that I had a look at the MSDN docs, there is a note that in Vista and later, you should use KNOWNFOLDERID instead of CLSID values. Does that also apply if my app must run on XP?

Comment: No, I think it's for Vista only

Comment: I'll likely go with another folder (see my comments to the question), but this is the best answer to the question, so I accepted it. Thanks for your prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

For clarification - By common desktop do you mean C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop?

If yes, this is an ugly hack -

```
Dim c As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
Dim comDesktop As String = c.Substring(0, c.LastIndexOf("\")) + "\Desktop"
```

Comment: Yes, I mean that. But it's really to ugly.

Comment: It's going to break as soon as some system uses other name for Desktop :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Script Host - WshShell.SpecialFolders

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea7b5xe(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I'd rather p/invoke than introduce such a dependency :)

Answer (score 0):

First, add a reference to "Windows Script Host Object Model". You'll find this in the COM tab of the "Add References" dialog.

```
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;

object commonUserDesktop = "AllUsersDesktop";
WshShell shell = new WshShellClass();
string commonPath = shell.SpecialFolders.Item(ref commonUserDesktop).ToString();
```

Comment: Like I wrote at Bogdan_Ch's answer, I'd rather not use WSH for such a task. P/Invoke is fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (yes it is also ugly and will work probably only on Windows XP, not on Vista)
is to read a value from registry

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders , Common Desktop

Comment: This is not only ugly, but a compatibility nightmare. If I remember correctly, it even was only in some CTP version of Windows, but since applications relied on it, it has to be in Windows for decades.